# Finding "1-to-3" links in a relational database

Tags: database, theory

I'm sure there's a term for this I just don't know, but let's call it finding the "1-to-3" links. Assume I have a table like so:

```
ID  Src     Src_Field  Tgt      Tgt_Field
1   Table1  Field_A    Table2   Field_D
2   Table1  Field_B    Table2   Field_E
3   Table1  Field_C    Table2   Field_F
4   Table2  Field_D    Table3   Field_G
5   Table2  Field_E    Table3   Field_H
6   Table2  Field_F    Table3   Field_I
```

I'd like the final result to look like so:

```
Table1  Field_A Table2  Field_D Table3  Field_G
Table1  Field_B Table2  Field_E Table3  Field_H
Table1  Field_C Table2  Field_F Table3  Field_I
```

I'm not looking for someone to write a query for me as much as I'm looking for what this is called, a link to an algorithm, etc. I'm trying to find these links and pair them:

```
1 => 2
2 => 3
```

So I get:

```
1 => 2 => 3
```

Hence my term "1-to-3" link. The actual relational database is unimportant. I'm primarily looking to learn about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe this as a *[hierarchical database model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model)*.

> A hierarchical database model is a data model in which the data is
>   organized into a tree-like structure.

A *[recursive join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_join)* would be used to get the results you've provided.

> The recursive join is an operation used in relational databases, also
>   sometimes called a "fixed-point join". It is a compound operation that
>   involves repeating the join operation, typically accumulating more
>   records each time, until a repetition makes no change to the results
>   (as compared to the results of the previous iteration).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I'm looking for.